# Unable to declare variable named "location" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why I am unable to use `location` as a variable name?

When I create a variable like below, chrome and firefox reloads the page over and over again.

```
var location = '';
```

Comment: Don't use global variables with [that name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global variables in the browser are automatically properties of the `window` object. Assigning to `window.location` is how you perform a redirect in Javascript. E.g.

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
```

will redirect the page to Google.

An empty URL means to use the URL of the current page, so you're telling it to redirect to itself, which just keeps reloading the page.

Rename your variable so it doesn't conflict with any of the window properties that have special meaning. Or make it a local variable inside a function; you can use an IIFE for this.

```
(function() {
    var location = '';
})();
```