# Passed parameter hyperlink to JavaScript function always NULL

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have in my ASP code:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" id="btnRedirect" onclick="redirect()"><u>Click here</u></a>
```

And in my script:

```
function redirect() {
      var location = document.getElementById('Locations').value;
      window.open('/../Direct/NewPage.aspx?Location=' + location, 'List', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=990,height=600,left=530,top=200');
}
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to get the selected value of a Dropdown and pass it into a new window. The dropdown itself is definitely not null, as it is populated and a value pre-selected when the page itself loads. I've also confirmed that the URL itself is correct. When I attempt to click, nothing happens. I checked my console for any logs, and got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at redirect (OldPage.aspx:16:67)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

I'm just not sure if this is due to a syntax issue, or something else. My values are certainly not null as they're being used elsewhere on the page. I made sure to have IDs, and my dropdown itself has one:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Locations" Width="40%" Autopostback="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: `location` is a reserved keyword. Use a different set of characters for your variable name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to declare variable named "location" in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686677/unable-to-declare-variable-named-location-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I changed the variable name, but that did not change anything; I still receive the same error.

Comment: Then the ID is incorrect. ASP.NET does change the IDs of server-rendered controls. Look at the rendered HTML. Use a CSS class name instead.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Checking the rendered code after inspecting the error allowed me to find the issue: The server-rendered did indeed change the name of the ID (well, it simply added ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ to the beginning of the ID).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641280/reference-asp-net-control-by-id-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the Generated HTML: Use your browser's developer tools (usually accessible by pressing F12) to inspect the rendered HTML for the `DropDownList`. Look for the select element generated by the `<asp:DropDownList>` control and note the id attribute's actual value. It will likely be different from just Locations.

`ClientIDMode` Property: If you have control over the ASP.NET version and configuration, you can use the `ClientIDMode` property of the `DropDownList` to control how the client-side id is generated. Setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` makes ASP.NET render the client-side id attribute exactly as you've specified in the ID property, making it predictable and easier to reference in JavaScript.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Locations" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="40%" Autopostback="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

With `ClientIDMode="Static"`, your original JavaScript code should work as expected because the client-side id will match the server-side ID.

Verify AutoPostBack: The `Autopostback="true"` attribute in your `<asp:DropDownList>` tag is correctly spelled as `AutoPostBack="true"`. This might be a typo in your question, but ensure it's correct in your code to avoid other issues.